# Does DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks in .NET match any standard?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, .net-core, timestamp

Investigating the data sent/received via an web API. I found that in some places they are sending/receiving the long value of `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`. It is used to describe a specific point in time (e.g. in the meaning of valid until).

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-5.0) explain what they are but I am actually wondering if this matches any standard?
It's definitly not unix epoch or something in my opinion. So how would you describe it for a client that consumes the API but is not developed in C#?

Answer (score 2):

Ticks in C# are very well defined:

> ... represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 in the Gregorian calendar. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-5.0

Unless you need 100-nanosecond accuracy (which is unlikely), I suggest you start using [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which looks something like YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.fffZ, and is very well supported in most languages.

Comment: Yes, in the body iso 8601 is the typical format I (or JSON) tends to use. But ISO 8601 seems not to be URL safe and the API I am investigating is using them as URL parameters. And yes, it it is well defined in the docs but it is not a commonly recognized standard, or is it?

Comment: Just think about that for a moment.  Why would you use one standard in the body and another in the URL?   ISO8601 is safe in a URL, assuming you encode it, and encoding is generally handled automatically anyway, assuming you aren't hand-crafting URL strings (which you shouldn't be doing).

Comment: just to make sure: you got the point that the code isn't by me and I am investigating a foreign API and I am not going to rewrite it. :-)